# Generate one output file from a YAML source

Tags: html, maven, swagger

I am using a sample code provided from a [YAML tutorial](https://gitlab.doc.ic.ac.uk/hdk216/musicPlaylistAPI/blob/431f728670696eb94053a19060f4050d36f7aa42/documentation/swaggerUI/src/main/html/swagger.yaml).

I use Maven to generate HTML/PDF file from this YAML source. The POM file (snippet) is shown at the end of this post.

I have successfully generated output files, but there are 4 HTMLs (`definitions.html`, `overview.html`, `paths.html`, and `security.html`). 
Just wondering, is that possible to have *only* one output file to be generated? Should I change anything in the POM?

The POM file (snippet):

```
<plugin>
<groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger2markup-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${swagger2markup.version}</version>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger2markup-import-files-ext</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger2markup.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.swagger2markup</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger2markup-spring-restdocs-ext</artifactId>
      <version>${swagger2markup.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<configuration>
  <swaggerInput>${swagger.input}</swaggerInput>
  <outputDir>${generated.asciidoc.directory}</outputDir>
  <config>
    <swagger2markup.markupLanguage>ASCIIDOC</swagger2markup.markupLanguage>
    <!--<swagger2markup.basePathPrefixEnabled>true</swagger2markup.basePathPrefixEnabled>-->
    <swagger2markup.listDelimiterEnabled>true</swagger2markup.listDelimiterEnabled>
  </config>
</configuration>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>convertSwagger2markup</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
  <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${asciidoctor.maven.version}</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
      <artifactId>asciidoctorj-pdf</artifactId>
      <version>${asciidoctorj.pdf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
      <artifactId>asciidoctorj</artifactId>
      <version>${asciidoctorj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <!-- Configure generic document generation settings -->
  <configuration>
    <sourceDirectory>${asciidoctor.input.directory}</sourceDirectory>
    <attributes>
      <doctype>book</doctype>
      <toc>left</toc>
      <toclevels>3</toclevels>
      <numbered></numbered>
      <hardbreaks></hardbreaks>
      <sectlinks></sectlinks>
      <sectanchors></sectanchors>
      <generated>${generated.asciidoc.directory}</generated>
    </attributes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>output-html</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <backend>html5</backend>
        <outputDirectory>${asciidoctor.html.output.directory}</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>output-pdf</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
          <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
          <backend>pdf</backend>
          <outputDirectory>${asciidoctor.pdf.output.directory}</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am facing similar issue. How to combine definitions and paths into single file so that all hyperlink works?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [documentation of the Asciidoctor Maven Plugin configuration options](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctor-maven-plugin/#configuration-options) leaves plenty of room for improvement and also:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'help' in plugin org.asciidoctor:asciidoctor-maven-plugin:1.5.5
among available goals auto-refresh, http, process-asciidoc, zip
```

you could use the [Maven Shade Plugin with its [Xml]AppendingTransformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer):

> ... to merge them by appending their content into one file.